# vbs log out with delay

Tags: vbscript, delay, logout

I want to log out my computer with delay in a vbscript. Here is what i've tried so far:

```
Dim ObjShell
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell = msgbox("Wollen Sie den Computer herunterfahren ?", +vbYesNo+vbExclamation, "")
If ObjShell = 6 then
Set ShellObject = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Primary=true")
For Each sys In ShellObject
Sys.Win32Shutdown 0
Next
End if
```

I do want to know how i can create a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WScript.Exec "shutdown.exe -L -F -t 30"` to let the waiting be done by  shutdown or use `Wscript.Sleep 30000` to initiate a wait before the next statement is executed.

Both times are 30 seconds in this example.